# Power BI Dax Adding a Variance Column in a matrix

Tags: powerbi, dax, percentage, difference, calculation

I have matrix visual in a power bi dashboard that shows the average students' scores which looks like below.

[image]

I would like to add a column that shows variance which looks like below.

[image]

I know how to calculate the variance with DAX but I was not able to add it as one column. I could only add variances as 2 columns next to each of the 2 school years (where I only need ONE variance column!) like my second table.

This is how the raw data looks like.

[image]

Any idea is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to add a special measure to your model that returns the score if a single School and year is selected, and the variance otherwise.  Then the Score can be a column subtotal in the matrix.  EG

```
MatrixMeasure = if (HASONEVALUE(SchoolScore[School]) && HASONEVALUE(SchoolScore[Year]),
              sum(SchoolScore[Score]),
              CALCULATE(sum(SchoolScore[Score]),LASTNONBLANK(SchoolScore[Year],sum(SchoolScore[Score])))-CALCULATE(sum(SchoolScore[Score]),FIRSTNONBLANK(SchoolScore[Year],sum(SchoolScore[Score]))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a matrix, use a table table and calculate the columns yourself:

```
Year 2020/2021 = 
CALCULATE(
    AVERAGE('Table'[Score]),
    'Table'[Year] = "Year 2020/2021"
)
```

and

```
Year 2021/2022 = 
CALCULATE(
    AVERAGE('Table'[Score]),
    'Table'[Year] = "Year 2021/2022"
)
```

and

```
Variation = 
DIVIDE(
    STDEV.P('Table'[Score]),
    AVERAGE('Table'[Score])
)
```

combined in a table visual

[image]